# It sounds well or it sounds good?

Tags: adverbs, sense-verbs, predicate-adjectives

Is it possible and correct to use "well" with "to sound"? I am under the impression that most natives find it wrong. For example:

1 The guitar sounds good. - OK

2 The guitar sounds well. - Possible?

3 The sentence sounds good. - OK

4 The sentence sounds well. - Possible?

Comment: Uses grammar 'rules' of well and good are easily found with research.

Comment: You are right. But they don't explain all the subtleties.  According to the rule "well" modifies a verb which makes sentence 2 and 4 correct. But in practice, people cringe on hearing them. Go figure.

Comment: Unless  "the guitar" is the name of a whale diving deep  after being harpooned in yet another violation of the ONU agreements, NO.

Comment: Cascabel, sounds like a sarcastic point... what you are  getting at?

Comment: @user1425 It's a different meaning of the verb *sound*, used in whaling. That one takes an adverb to describe the diving. Sense verbs take adjectives like any other so-called linking verb (a bad term but oh well) because they describe the subject not the verb.

Comment: I'd like to persuade you that this is *not* quite the same question as the Discrepancy in using adjective or adverb with “taste” one. I think I can demonstrate a perfectly good usage of 'sounds well'. I'm a bit inexperienced in such things but is it possible to re-open this question so that I can post an answer? Thanks

Comment: Absolutely agree with you on that!

Comment: @lbf Forgot the "AT-sign lbf" !

Comment: @tchrist Hiya. I'd love your help here. How can I add an answer?

Answer (score -1):

***[It sounds good/great](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sounds-good-great-etc)***  is and idiomatic expression:

> used for telling someone that their idea or suggestion seems like a good one.
>
> - ‘How about dinner and a film tonight?’ ‘Sounds great.’

(MacMillan Dictionary)

Comment: No, it's not an idiomatic expression. Sense verbs take predicate adjectives describing the subject.